# changing HTML content of element with gradient text do not re render in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I have div element with some text inside. Text is gradient. When I try to change the content of the element it does not re-render in the browser. If I watch dom with inspect element, I can see that value is changing, [but in the page it stays same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrypO.png).
It works fine on firefox.

```
<style>
    .grad_font {
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient( #e3004a, #ffb201);
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( #e3004a, #dc3d27);
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        font-size: 44px;
        -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    }

</style>
<div>
    <div id="grad_price" class="tariff_cena grad_font">
        <div class="tariff_cena_number">25.188</div>
    </div>

    <button onclick="changeTariff()">click</button>
</div>
<script>
    function changeTariff() {
        document.querySelector('.tariff_cena_number').innerHTML = Math.random();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You should not use prefixes (`-webkit`), unless necessary, `linear-gradient` is well-supported. Also, only use `background` **or** `background-image`. Regarding the main issue: Looks like a bug, would report it on the Chromium issue tracker (then again, you are using non-standard features, which may even be removed if they are not standardized...).

Comment: Yes, prefixes stayed there after many attempts of trying to fix :) but in this case, it doesn't change anything. Not working this way or that way. It might be the result of removing non-standard features because this worked for a few months and suddenly stopped after chrome update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding from @suspectus's answer it works if you reference offsetHeight.

Eg:

```
e.style.display = 'none';
e.offsetHeight;
e.style.display = 'block';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could draw re-displaying the element. Note this assumes your `div` is block type element. If not, just change the display type to suit.

```
function changeTariff() {
    document.querySelector('.tariff_cena_number').innerHTML = Math.random();
    var e = document.querySelector('#grad_price');
    e.style.display = 'none';
    e.style.display = 'block';  
}
```

Comment: It does not work with this workaround. I tried something similar also. Removing grad_font before changing a value, change the value, and then add grad_font class again. Then the problem is different. It does re-render, but don't remove the old view. It just renders one on another :)

Comment: interesting, ok will delete this.